# Python - change a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary:
{**(1, 1): 4,**
 (1, 2): 2,
 (1, 3): 5,
 **(2, 2): 7,**
 (2, 3): 1}

and I would like to keep these indexes where the pair number is the same :
**{1: 4,
 2: 5}**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand how this input creates this output. Also show what you have tried already (edit the question).

Comment: Should the output be `{1: 4, 2: 7}`?

Comment: Also what have you tried already?

Comment: `{k1: v for (k1, k2), v in d.items() if k1 == k2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in just one line:

```
d = {(1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 2, (1, 3): 5, (2, 2): 7, (2, 3): 1}
new_d = {i[0]:j for i,j in d.items() if i[0]==i[1]}
```

The out put will be :

```
In [4]: new_d                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[4]: {1: 4, 2: 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_dict = {(1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 2, (1, 3): 5, (2, 2): 7, (2, 3): 1}
output_dict ={}
for int_tuple, value in input_dict.items():
    if int_tuple[0] == int_tuple[1]:
        output_dict[int_tuple[0]] = value
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {(1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 2, (1, 3): 5, (2, 2): 7, (2, 3): 1}
newD = {k[0]: v for (k,v) in d.items() if len(set(k)) == 1}
print(newD)
```

Output:

```
{1: 4, 2: 7}
```